# How can I reference an array items' type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

One can refer to the types of interface properties in TypeScript with the following syntax: `Person['gender']`, so the following is valid TypeScript:

```
interface Person {
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
  addresses: {
    city: string,
    street: string
  }[];
}

let person: Person = {
  gender: 'male',
  addresses: [],
};

let gender: Person['gender'] = person.gender;
```

Is it possible to somehow get the **array item type** of Person['addresses'] the same way?

*Disclaimer: I understand that in this toy example it could be easily inferred. I also understand that the whole issue could be avoided by creating an Address interface, but sometimes it is less verbose overall and more easily followable if one refers to some types this way.*

Answer (score 9):

The following is valid TypeScript, albeit it's a bit weird looking:

```
let address: Person['addresses'][0] = {
  city: 'Budapest',
  street: 'Kossuth',
}
```